# Large Prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Say we have $2^{690} + 345^4$ and we want to figure out whether this is a prime number. 
I feel that we could break down the numbers into their respective prime factors (prime factorization) and use modular arithmetic to calculate whether these numbers are prime numbers or not. 
$690 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 23$ and $345 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 23$

How should I proceed?

Comment: It has a small prime factor (just by trial and error).

Answer (score 6):

We could render the number as:

$345^4+4·(2^{172})^4$

$\equiv a^4+4b^4$ which factors as

$(a^2+2ab+2b^2)·(a^2-2ab+2b^2)$.

We then have no doubt that this number is composite.

Comment: Very good answer, but I would add one little argument : $$a^2-2ab+2b^2=(a-b)^2+b^2>1$$ for $b\ge 2$ , just to rule out that the second factor is $1$

Answer (score 0):

The factor lulu means is $17$. To show $$2^{690}+345^4\equiv 0\mod 17$$ you can reduce the exponents modulo $\phi(17)=16$ and the bases modulo $17$. This gives $2^2+5^4$. Since $5^2\equiv 8\mod 17$ and $5^4\equiv 8^2\equiv 13\equiv-4\mod 17$, we get $$2^2+5^4\equiv 4+(-4)=0\mod 17$$

Comment: Since the given number is odd and a sum of two coprime squares, you only need to check the prime divisors of the form $4k+1$, hence the primes $5,13,17$. $5$ can easily be ruled out because the second summand is divisble by $5$. Checking $13$ will show that it is not a factor, but $17$ will turn out to be a factor.